# Git hook for any action that updates the working directory

Tags: git, githooks

Following an answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305744/embed-git-revision-in-executable-during-remote-build-with-netbeans), I implemented a Git hook script which needs to fire whenever the working directory is updated.  I linked this script to the following in .git/hooks:

- post-checkout
- post-commit
- post-merge

This mostly works, but not always.  One case I found is `git stash`.  This is a problem because my hook generates a text file wihch I also mark with `git update-index --assume-unchanged` to tell Git that I don't want to check in changes (an empty version is checked in).  However, `git stash` will revert the assume-unchanged file (to the empty file), which means the hook needs to run again, yet the hook is not invoked after `git stash`.

I suspect a similar problem may exist with `git rebase` too, but that's not as easy to explain.

I want a hook which Git will *always* run after updating the working directory.  Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try a [`git update-index --skip-worktree`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/6309), to see if the file if also affected by the git stash?

Comment: I had no idea about `--skip-worktree`.  Now I have tried it, and it does seem to do what I want.  If you add that to your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about `git stash pop` (I offer some alternative in "[Is there a way with to prevent “git stash pop” from marking files as modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14274272/6309)").

[`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) comes with another option `--skip-worktree`, which might avoid the git stash issue.
See "[Git - Difference Between '`assume-unchanged`' and '`skip-worktree`'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree/13631525#13631525)"

---

But for `git rebase`, you could be interested in the **[`post-rewrite` hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post-rewrite)**:

> This hook is invoked by commands that rewrite commits (`git commit --amend`, `git-rebase`; currently `git-filter-branch` does not call it!).
>   Its first argument denotes the command it was invoked by: currently one of amend or rebase. Further command-dependent arguments may be passed in the future.
>
> The hook receives a list of the rewritten commits on stdin, in the format

```
<old-sha1> SP <new-sha1> [ SP <extra-info> ] LF
```

> The `extra-info` is again command-dependent. If it is empty, the preceding SP is also omitted. Currently, no commands pass any extra-info.

Comment: I tried post-rewrite, and it does not solve the `git stash` problem (note that even `git stash` is a problem, not only `git stash pop`).  So thanks for the tip, I may make use of it for rebase later, but I still need a solution for stash.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I agree. My answer was for the "`git rebase`" part. I only offer a link for the git stash, but nothing conclusive.