# CMake: How to create a file with make command

Tags: c++, linux, file, cmake

I need to create the following always-out-of-date file: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/version.hpp.in
before any target is executed in the make file. The content of file is exactly as the following:

> #define RELEASE_VERSION "${RELEASE}"
>   #define MAJOR_VERSION "${MAJOR}"
>   #define MINOR_VERSION "${MINOR}"
>   #define PATCH_VERSION "${PATCH}"
>   #define REVISION "${REVISION}"
>   #define SVNPATH "${SVNPATH}"

I've got the following piece of code in my CMake file, but it's executed only after running the `cmake` command:

```
FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/version.hpp.in
"#define RELEASE_VERSION \"${RELEASE}\"\n"
"#define MAJOR_VERSION \"${MAJOR}\"\n"
"#define MINOR_VERSION \"${MINOR}\"\n"
"#define PATCH_VERSION \"${PATCH}\"\n"
"#define REVISION \"${REVISION}\"\n"
"#define SVNPATH \"${SVNPATH}\"\n"
)
```

I want to generate the `version.hpp.in` file each time I run the `make` command. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `configure_file()` for this:

```
configure_file(version.hpp.in ${DESTPATH}/version.hpp)
```

Where `DESTPATH` is optional and set to the path you want that file.

> If the  file is modified the build system will re-run CMake to re-configure the file and generate the build system again.

*(Source: Documentation, see below)*

**File `version.hpp`:**

```
#define RELEASE_VERSION "${RELEASE}"
#define MAJOR_VERSION "${MAJOR}"
#define MINOR_VERSION "${MINOR}"
#define PATCH_VERSION "${PATCH}"
#define REVISION "${REVISION}"
#define SVNPATH "${SVNPATH}"
```

**Syntax:**

```
configure_file(<input> <output>
               [COPYONLY] [ESCAPE_QUOTES] [@ONLY]
               [NEWLINE_STYLE [UNIX|DOS|WIN32|LF|CRLF] ])
```

**Documentation:**

- [CMake 3.0](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html#command:configure_file)
- [CMake 2.8.12](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:configure_file)

---

```
# 'example' is the targetname here, eg. using add_executable(example example.cpp)

add_custom_command(TARGET example PRE_BUILD COMMAND <CMAKE COMMAND HERE>)
```

---

### Minimal Example

#### Version.h.in

```
#define VERSION ${VERSION}
```

Just for testing …

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

set(VERSION 1.10)
set(TEMPLATE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(example example.cpp)

add_custom_command(TARGET example PRE_BUILD 
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SetVersion.cmake)
```

#### SetVersion.cmake

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Version.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Version.h)
message("Version set") # For testing only
```

Now run `cmake` and `make` as usual and check if `HELLO` is printed on `make`.

Comment: The point is that I'm already using the `configure_file`! The `version.hpp.in` file that I'm trying to generate is supposed to be the <input> file of the `configure_file` command. The problem is that `configure_file` is executed only after <input> has been modified. That's why I am trying to always generate the <input> file (version.hpp.in) so that `configure_file` is always executed.

Comment: I see, so you may test `add_custom_command()`, eg. as stated [here](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/configure-file-as-a-build-step-td7518670.html). I hope this helps more.

Comment: Could you please do me a favor and integrate that in your answer? I can't get a grasp of it...

Comment: A question to understand your problem a bit better: If you change a variable, eg. `RELEASE` in your cmake file, running `make` should also re-run cmake.

Comment: Even if you delete the configured file, it will be created again on `make`. Btw. what version of cmake are you using? *-- 5 min edit time was over :-(*

Comment: cmake version: 2.8.10.1. No, if I remove the configured file, the `configure_file` command wont be executed because its input has not changed.

Comment: Strange, i'm using Cmake 3.0.2 and if i remove the generated file and run make, it's created again.

Comment: I've added a small example, just have to finally get the correct command to execute. Btw. for testing you can replace `<CMAKE COMMAND HERE>` with `echo HELLO` - if hello is shown on `make`, we are ok so far.

Comment: 'Hello' is printed, I also just upgraded to 3.0.2. What cmake command should I use instead of `echo HELLO`?

Comment: Ok, but the problem isn't fixed with 3.0.2, isn't it? I'll edit the rest into my answer, just give me some minutes.

Comment: No it wasn't fixed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a few works: the generation of the config file is done in an extra cmake file. As command `cmake -P <that file>` is used. This means: Cmake runs just that single file (where the configs are set) instead of the full cmakelists. Just *beware of the paths*!

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you put on this. I have to leave the office now. I will try to get it working the other that as soon as I can and will update you.

Comment: I almost got your solution working. The only problem is that the `VERSION` variable is not known in the `SetVersion.cmake` file, unless I pass this variable to the `SetVersion.cmake` file like this: `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DVERSION=${VERSION} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SetVersion.cmake`. Correct? Please take a look at the followup question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26216570/69537

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I hope i understand you correct, but you can place the variable in the cache - see documentation of `set()`. Did you test that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_custom_command` (and perhaps `add_custom_target`) to do this sort of thing.

Since you're asking about building version symbols into your program, I will tell you about a slightly different method that I use.  I asked a question related to it here, with some code: [Embed Git revision in executable during remote build with NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305744/embed-git-revision-in-executable-during-remote-build-with-netbeans)

The concept I use is to generate actual symbols in an object file directly from a textual file which I write at build (or `git pull`) time.  Then I link this file into the executable.

Comment: `configure_file` is the defacto. Not `objcopy`