# Can I use add_custom_command(... PRE_BUILD ...) on a target to generate sources for that target?

Tags: cmake

I would like to set up a custom command in `cmake` to generate some files (`.h`) before building our test binary, which uses those files during compilation.

My first attempt was to add the custom command to `PRE_BUILD` the target:

```
add_executable(mytest ${SRCS})

add_custom_command(
   TARGET mytest PRE_BUILD
   COMMAND <generate my_file.h>
   BYPRODUCTS my_file.h
)

target_sources(mytest PRIVATE my_file.h)
```

But when I attempt to build `mytest` the impl file (`my_file.cpp`) complains that `my_file.h` isn't found:

```
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/my_test.cpp.o
/usr/redacted/project/my_test.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'my_test.h' file not found
#include "my_test.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

So I attempted to move the impl file from `${SRCS}` and explicitly add it after the generated file was added:

```
#same as above

target_sources(mytest PRIVATE my_file.h)
target_sources(mytest PRIVATE my_file.cpp)
```

But that didn't seem to work either.

I have `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)` with 3.25.1 installed.

Comment: "But when I attempt to build `mytest` the impl file (`my_file.cpp`) complains that `my_file.h` isn't found." - How exactly it complains? Please, add **exact error message** to the question post.

Comment: Added. My custom_command command is never firing either. I tried to change it to be a separate library: `add_library(mylib my_file.cpp`) and change the `add_custom_command(TARGET mylib PRE_BUILD ...)` to target it, and just `make mylib` and it still fails.

Comment: Ah, more searching came up with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26217660/868247

Comment: I was trying to refactor the code so the thing that needs the generated files (the test) was responsible for building them. Currently, I have the generated files as a `POST_BUILD` step on the generation target. I saw the `PRE_BUILD` option and was like, perfect. Obviously not.

Comment: If you use `add_custom_command(OUTPUT)` and list one of the outputs as a source of a binary target, cmake will ensure the files are up to date judging by the parameters provided to `add_custom_command`. If you want a generation target, use `add_custom_target()` and list the files generated by `add_custom_command()` among the files the target `DEPENDS` on. Then use `add_dependencies` to add the custom target as dependency of the target using the generated stuff and the files are updated as necessary, plus you're able to manually run the generation step by building the custom target...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use add_custom_command(... PRE_BUILD ...) on a target to generate sources for that target?

No you cannot. See [the docs for `PRE_BUILD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events), which state:

> On [Visual Studio Generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#visual-studio-generators), run before any other rules are executed within the target. On other generators, run just before `PRE_LINK` commands.

I.e. The command does not run before the compilation of sources, which you need it to, since you're generating a header, which presumably you want to `#include` in those sources. The same applies for non-headers, which need to be compiled.

What you *can* do is generate the header / source file using the other signature of `add_custom_command`: [the "generating files" signature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#generating-files) (instead of the "build events" signature). Ex.

```
add_executable(mytest ${SRCS})
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT my_file.h
   COMMAND <generate my_file.h>
   # any other arguments as necessary, Ex. DEPENDS
   VERBATIM
)
target_sources(mytest PRIVATE my_file.h)
```

When you do that, CMake will notice that the output file is used as a source file for another target, and generate a buildsystem that ensures the output file is generated before building that target, and that rebuilds both in order if the output file changes (Ex. it will generate a buildsystem to update the output file if any files in the `DEPENDS` argument change).

Other approaches may include (if appropriate), using [`file(GENERATE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#generate), or [`configure_file(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html).

See also Craig Scott (one of the CMake maintainers)'s post on this topic [here](https://crascit.com/2017/04/18/generated-sources-in-cmake-builds/).

Comment: Thanks, the doc is worded poorly, as it starts with "Visual Studio Generators" so I just ignored the whole paragraph. But the second sentence is obviously important.